# PowerShell - SupportsShouldProcess within script property

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm getting a null expression when I try to access a variable within the ShouldProcess script-block. This is what I have in a script method:

```
$scaObject = [PerfWorker.CmdLets.PSDbInfoFactory]::GetPSDbInfo($info, $false)
$oracleObj = [PerfWorker.CmdLets.OracleParamsDto]$scaObject
Add-Member -InputObject $oracleObj -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name DropSchemas -Value {      
    $oraWorker = [PerfWorker.CmdLets.PSDbOracleInfo]$this.DbWorker                         
    $args | foreach {                                                                       
        #Start getting error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" from line below
        if($psCmdLet.ShouldProcess(                                       
            "Delete Oracle Schema $_ on $($this.Hostname)? This action cannot be undone!",  
            "Delete Schema?"))                                                              
        {
            $oraWorker.DropS3DSchemas($_)                                       
        }                                                                               
    }
}
```

If I remove the `$psCmdlet.ShouldProcess` block and just call the `$oraWorker.DropS3DSchemas()` method, then everything works fine.

Comment: Did you include the `[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]` attribute at the beginning of your function?

Comment: Yes it is there as [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]

Comment: Can you provide full exception?

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be mixing the cmdlet execution context with the execution context of a script method on an object.  The script method code is captured in a scriptblock that is run later outside the context of the cmdlet method that created it.  Before the `if` check if `$PSCmdlet -eq $null`.  I don't think you can do what you're trying to do here.  The `ShouldProcess()` needs to execute in the context of your cmdlet.  The PowerShell way would be to create a Drop-Schemas cmdlet that does the work.  Then you can use the `ShouldProcess()` feature in that cmdlet.

Comment: Yes i was afraid of that. The reason I'm adding the script method is because it's database dependent - MSSQL ones don't have it in my case. I guess then I can add another function and invoke that...